# UITableViewController unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa17c1f0

Tags: xcode, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

I am new in iOS Development and currently I am working on a Tabbed Application which contains 4 tabs. On one of my tabs I am trying to display a table view but i get the following error.

**2013-03-13 14:15:35.416 STAM[4054:c07] -[UITableViewController setProducts:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa17c1f0**

I created a ProductsViewController class which is a subclass of UITableViewController, and also i hooked up the TableViewController to the ProductViewController in the StoryBoard.

I also created a Product class where I inserted the following properties:

Product.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface Product : NSObject
 @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
 @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *number;
 @end
```

In AppDelegate.m i did the following:

```
@implementation AppDelegate {
NSMutableArray *products;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    products = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];

Product *product = [[Product alloc] init];
product.name = @"Test Product";
product.number = @"123546";
[products addObject:product];

product = [[Product alloc] init];
product.name = @"Test Product 2";
product.number = @"654321";
[products addObject:product];

UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
ProductsViewController *productsViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
productsViewController.products = products;

return YES;
}
```

And finally in the ProductViewController.h:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [self.products count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ProductCell"];
Product *product = [self.products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = product.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = product.number;

    return cell;
}
```

I really don't know where to look for the error.

Thank you very much!

Granit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
productsViewController.products = products;
```

Is converted to:

```
[productsViewController setProducts: products];
```

In the code you provided there is no mention of a 'read-write' products property nor have you provided the above method.  You might normally do this with:

```
@interface ProductViewController ...
@property (readwrite) NSArray *products
// ...
@end


@implementation ProductViewController
@synthesize products
// ...
@end
```